# Use AWS CLI to invoke API Gateway in a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I have an API Gateway configured in **Account A**.

I am trying to invoke the GET method using the CLI from an EC2 instance in **Account B**:

```
aws --region us-east-1 apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id xxxxxxxxxx --resource-id xxxxxx --http-method GET
```

The EC2 instance in **Account B** has an Instance Profile attached to it that allows `apigateway:*`.  The API Gateway in **Account A** has a policy that allows execution from the EC2 instance in **Account B**.

When I run the command, I get the error::

> An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the TestInvokeMethod operation: Invalid API identifier specified xxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxx

The first set of 'x' in the error refer to **Account B** (instead of **Account A**), and the second set of 'x' refer to the rest-api-id.

Comment: The [Controlling access to an API with API Gateway resource policies - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html) documentation does specifically reference "Users from a specified AWS account", so it should be possible. Please Edit your question to show the API Gateway resource policy.

Comment: Use a simple http client tool like `curl` to trigger the API endpoint.